# Want to change phalcon default route

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I want to change the default route in `phalcon`, which is an index action of `indexcontroller`.

My `routes.php`:

```
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
//Define a route
$router->add(
    "/",
    array(
        "controller" => "admin", //previously it was "index" 
        "action"     => "index",
    )
);
$router->handle();
```

Now when I open my site (for example `http://localhost/test/`) in a browser it gives me error:

```
IndexController handler class cannot be loaded

#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->_throwDispatchException('IndexController...', 2)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#2 C:\wamp\www\test\public\index.php(36): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#3 {main}
```

I'm confused why my route is going to `indexcontroller` even after replacing it in the routes file?

Comment: Maybe silly, but did you copy your file without changing class name?

Comment: no that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to set your default controller you need to use-

```
$router->setDefaults(array(
   'controller' => 'admin',
   'action' => 'index'  
));
```

Comment: Wow it's working. You saved my day. But i had never wrote this line in my previous project and it's still working fine.